# hostdef extension doesn't exist oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

Hi i need help with this error:
hostdef extension doesn't exist oracle 11g which i get when i am trying to connect to database. i have tried to:
 1. restart XE Listener 
 2. ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are correctly set.
i have found that this is due to real memory but did not find how to liberate it in windows, i found that in unix one can use ipcrm command.

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = XE)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
))
XE=(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MACHINE_NAME)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you try to reboot the computer (saying that this is XE, I presume it is your own PC so you can afford it)?

Comment: Thank you Littlfout for your response, i tried to reboot but it didn't work, so i was obligated to reinstall oracle

Comment: I hope it solved the problem; thank you for letting us know!